# How fast would the ship have to have flown in Flight of the Navigator?

Tags: flight-of-the-navigator

In [*Flight of the Navigator*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091059/), a near-lightspeed flight causes the protagonist to not age whilst his family all age ~10 years.

How fast did the ship need to travel for that amount of time contraction?

Comment: Migrate to physics.SE? Its a fictional situation but not fictional physics.

Comment: You'd also need to know exactly how much time passed for David.

Comment: @Manishearth I think, while it is not fictional physics, there is not enough information to make it a physics question. It is more about interpreting the film, IMO.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place but if you're interested in this concept try _Tau Zero_ by Poul Anderson.

Comment: @SchroedingersCat Well, maybe. IIRC there are factors other than the velocity involved. I think that the formula is $\int \1/\gamma dt$, so it's not just velocity, but how it evolves over time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the trivia on IMDB - the link in the OP:

> David's flight to Phaelon and back took "4.4 Solar Hours," while 8 years have passed on Earth, indicating that time was slowed down for David by a factor of about 16,000, which corresponds to a speed of about 99.9999998% the speed of light.

So it took 4.4 hours. Of course, at this portion of the speed of light, very small differences can have a huge impact. So this question cannot be clearly answered without far more - and more accurate - information.

[Edit} Even more information, from IMDB:

> ... David should have returned 1120 years later, not 8, given the distance of 560 light years to Phaelon. To generate an eight year time lag, Phaelon has to be about four light years away, not 560

I don't know how they get the 560 light years away, but this would indicate that they travelled substatially fasted - over 100 times the speed of light to get to somewhere that far away in that time.

And I think they are wrong, because Phaelon needs to be 2.2 light years away, as they need to get there and back.

Comment: Using [the equation for time dilation](http://www.thebigview.com/spacetime/timedilation.html) and the `t` and `t'` values you've provided, we can calculate a more exact value for `v`:
`sqrt( 1 - (4.4 / (8*365.25*24)) ^ 2 ) = .99999999803169c`.

Comment: That's only about 0.6 m/s slower than the speed of light.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty close to the actual speed of light(99.9%).

The closer you get to light speed the slower time would seem to go from people looking at you not so close to the speed of light.

From memory 90% the speed of light slows you down to 50% (everything takes twice as long) 95% slows it down to 10% and 99% slows it down to 1% (i'm probably of a few percent on the speed of light part)